# Context Path in JSP Import

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I am trying to migrate an application, which was on WebSphere to Tomcat. Not to mention some other tools have changed as well, like ant to maven. After configuring all the projects, the There are multiple WAR files deployed. Now a JSP in war A is looking for a JSP in war B, because of an import statement.

```
<c:import url="/jsp/menu_head.jsp" context="/" />
```

This is what it was coded in the old code. But when I trying to run the application on Tomcat, I have to change it to:

```
<c:import url="/jsp/menu_head.jsp" context="/WebHome" />
```

So that Tomcat can detect the path. I can do it this way, but with more than 1000 JSPs to change, it will take months. Is there a quicker way to change the context, whether be it while building the WAR (web.xml or pom) or some Tomcat configuration? I read something called `crossContext` in Tomcat, and I enabled it like this:

```
    <Context crossContext="true">

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

   </Context>
```

I am not sure if this is the full configuration needed, as documentation/examples were scarce around it. I thought it would work, but it didn't. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `crossContext` doesn't do what you think it does. Put it back to the default.

Comment: If you want to reference resources in another context, you will have to specify the context name. I'm not sure how you were able to do this in WebSphere without specifying the context if it's different. If you are referring to resources in the *same* web application, then the default is to use the "current web application."

Comment: If you need to change 1000+ files, then use [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and have it done in less than a second. No need for months of development time.